# Why Is my controller causing me so many issues?

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller

I keep getting an undefined variable error on comment on the view page.

This is the controller that is causing all of my issues:

```
 use Desk\Forms\MessageForm;
 use Desk\Records\MessageRecord;
 use Desk\Repositories\MessageRepository;

 class MessageController extends BaseController
 {

protected $messageForm;

public function __construct(MessageForm $messageForm, MessageRepository $messageRepository,
  MessageRecord $messageRecord)
{
    $this->messageForm = $messageForm;
    $this->messageRepository = $messageRepository;
    $this->messageRecord = $messageRecord;
}

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 * GET /messages
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return View::make('comments.create');
}



public function display($comment)
{
    $message_id = $this->messageRepository->find($comment);
    return View::make('comments.show')->with('comment', $message_id);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 * POST /messaages
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store()
{
    $data = Input::all() ;
    $this->messageForm->validate($data);

    $messageRecord = new MessageRecord;
    $messageRecord->comment = $data['comment'];

    Return "Comment created";
}
}
```

And this is the view:

```
 <p>{{ $comment }}</p>
```

I can not understand what could be causing this much problems.

Comment: Please also post whats the output in your view or the error that your controller is causing

Comment: ErrorException
Undefined variable: comment (View: /desk/app/views/comments/show.blade.php)

Comment: Are you sure that $comment variable passed to function display is ok? Try return $comment; in function display to see the content of the variable.

Comment: The issue is the $comment and i don't know how to fix it.